# Excel sum formula over varying indices

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reproduce the sum of the values in column I within one cell, without having to evaluate them for each row individually. For better understanding see the following screenshot:

[image: My Sheet]

I've sifted through endless INDEX/INDIRECT/etc. results both here and on Google, but can't seem to figure it out... Basically I want to just sum over the row-wise evaluations of this formula:

```
=-MAX($B$1-MAX(A$1:A1)+MIN(A$1:A1),0)
```

Note that the starting row of each evaluation is fixed.

Edit: the solution proposed by Scott works *if* Excel recognizes the LET() function, which does not seem to be the case for my work laptop even though it has Office 365 Pro Plus, probably this latest insider program is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

With the dynamic array formula in Office 365:

```
=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A:A)),rng,OFFSET(A1,0,0,seq),SUMPRODUCT(-(B1-MAXIFS(rng,rng,"<>")+MINIFS(rng,rng,"<>"))*(B1-MAXIFS(rng,rng,"<>")+MINIFS(rng,rng,"<>")>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this formula break if there is a value between 0 and 10 entered in the data? I think the last part should be `((-B1-MAXIFS(rng,rng,"<>")+MINIFS(rng,rng,"<>"))>0)))`

Comment: It does.  But it is fixed now. @Axuary

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid there isn't any quick and dirty way to just replace the ":A1" with something like ":A{1,2,3,...}" using INDIRECT ...

Comment: Small edit: my Excel on my work laptop doesn't recognize LET(), although I have Office 365 Pro plus, any idea why that might be?